# How big a box can you wrap with a given polygon?

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, discrete-geometry, computational-geometry

**Question:** Given a convex polygonal region, how does one find the box (rectangular parallelopiped) of maximum volume that can be *wrapped* with this region? While wrapping, if needed, some portions of the polygon could overlap.

Possible variants to this question: replace box with say, sphere, cylinder  or any other *specific type* of 3D object; replace volume with say, surface area.

**Another Aspect:** In https://erikdemaine.org/wrapping/, is stated: " *if we can choose the piece of paper to be a thin rectangle, we can wrap a polyhedron with arbitrarily little wastage of paper: the amount of double coverage can be reduced to as close to zero as desired*". Guess the definition of wrapping can be modified to exclude such 'winding wraps'.

*Example:* Once winding wraps are excluded, if we consider a given triangle and try to find the largest sphere that can be wrapped by it, where should should we place largest sphere on triangle and wrap? The *incenter* is a natural guess but am doubtful.

Adding at bit on July 18th, 2021:

One can further ask the general question about the highest volume/surface area general convex polyhedron that can be wrapped by a given polygon - how to find/characterize it in simple cases when the polygon is a triangle etc..

One can also ask which is the least area convex polygon with which say, a unit cube can be wrapped - without windings.

Comment: No help with your questions, but you may know this universality result: Any polyhedron may be wrapped with a sufficiently large square sheet of paper. [Wrapping Polyhedra](https://erikdemaine.org/wrapping/).

Comment: Thank you! I understand that only the case of the largest *cube* that can be wrapped by a square is fully done; even wrapping disc appears to have open issues.  A note has been added to the Problem statement above.

Comment: As a silly application: If I have leaky tupperware to be wrapped in tin foil for transport, what is the largest container I can wrap with a piece of foil that was irregularly ripped?

Comment: For a circle of radius 1 wrapping a cube, you can place a cube with edge length 1/2 in the middle of the circle, and wrap around that -- is there any way to do better?

Comment: I can't see any bigger cube that can be wrapped by the unit circle!

Comment: Is it possible to give a reformulation of "wrapping the polyhedron A with the polygon B" in terms of the "planar development" of A? I don't know what's the word in English; for example, the planar development of a cube is made of six square faces, glued in forming a cross and lying on a plane. I guess finding a reformulation in terms of covering with prescribed shapes would be a good starting point.

Comment: Guess a planar development of any convex polyhedron would be a non-convex polygon. The question starts with convex polygons and tries to wrap boxes with it. But the planar development has the attraction of not featuring multiple windings.