# Multi-layered wrapping of polyhedra

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, discrete-geometry, computational-geometry

This post continues from [How big a box can you wrap with a given polygon?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/395954/how-big-a-box-can-you-wrap-with-a-given-polygon) and [Convex polyhedra that can be folded from convex polygons](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/396077/convex-polyhedra-that-can-be-folded-from-convex-polygons). One can also mention 'k-fold coverings of the plane' as examined in for example, '*Research problems in discrete geometry*' by Brass, Moser and Pach.

Consider wrapping convex polyhedrons with polygonal regions with the additional requirement: the wrap should be at least $n$ layers thick - from any point on the surface of the polyhedron, to go out into space, we have to cut thru a minimum of $n$ layers of the wrap formed by the polygon. Note: Portions of the wrap can have more than $n$ lavers due to overlap of portions of the polygon.

1. If a convex polyhedron cannot be wrapped (1-layer wrap) without overlaps by any convex polygon (eg. the cube), then, can it be 2-layer wrapped without overlaps by any convex polygon? The answer seems always negative.
2. Are there convex polygons other than the rectangle with which we can wrap *some* convex polyhedron with 3 layers without overlap? Maybe the answer is negative.
3. One can also ask: given a convex polygonal region, how big a sphere or box... can be 2-layer wrapped by it?

**Note:** A simpleminded approach to $n$-layer wrapping: First fold the wrapper polygon such that it is everywhere *at least* $n$ layers thick (how to do this folding to $n$-layers thickness seems nontrivial! A similar question was discussed at [On folding a polygonal sheet](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/365675/on-folding-a-polygonal-sheet)) and then wrap the given polyhedron with this multilayered wrapper. But it might lead to portions of the wrap having up to $2n$ layers thickness (wastage) and hence may fail to wrap the largest possible object.